# I'm getting an infinite loop with Swift when calling super.viewDidLoad() in two nested subclasses

Tags: ios, swift, crash, subclass

I'm working on an iOS app written in Swift. I have a subclass of UITabBarController, and then a nested subclass:

```
class HWTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
    }
}

class MainTabBarController: HWTabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
    }
}
```

This works fine in the iOS simulator, and even when I'm debugging the app on my iPhone. 
But it crashes when I archive the app and send it to my phone with TestFlight.

My crash logs are filled with this infinite loop:

```
22  HDWR                           0x00145e10 @objc HDWR.MainTabBarController.viewDidLoad (HDWR.MainTabBarController)() -> () (MainTabBarController.swift:16)
23  HDWR                           0x00262867 NRMA__voidParamHandler
24  HDWR                           0x0014ea00 HDWR.HWTabBarController.viewDidLoad (HDWR.HWTabBarController)() -> () (HWTabBarController.swift:24)
25  HDWR                           0x00145e10 @objc HDWR.MainTabBarController.viewDidLoad (HDWR.MainTabBarController)() -> () (MainTabBarController.swift:16)
26  HDWR                           0x00262867 NRMA__voidParamHandler
27  HDWR                           0x0014ea00 HDWR.HWTabBarController.viewDidLoad (HDWR.HWTabBarController)() -> () (HWTabBarController.swift:24)
28  HDWR                           0x00145e10 @objc HDWR.MainTabBarController.viewDidLoad (HDWR.MainTabBarController)() -> () (MainTabBarController.swift:16)
29  HDWR                           0x00262867 NRMA__voidParamHandler
30  HDWR                           0x0014ea00 HDWR.HWTabBarController.viewDidLoad (HDWR.HWTabBarController)() -> () (HWTabBarController.swift:24)
31  HDWR                           0x00145e10 @objc HDWR.MainTabBarController.viewDidLoad (HDWR.MainTabBarController)() -> () (MainTabBarController.swift:16)
32  HDWR                           0x00262867 NRMA__voidParamHandler
33  HDWR                           0x0014ea00 HDWR.HWTabBarController.viewDidLoad (HDWR.HWTabBarController)() -> () (HWTabBarController.swift:24)
```

What's the `voidParamHandler` instruction, and why does it lead back to `MainTabBarController.viewDidLoad`?

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is this a bug in Swift?

Comment: How is the class instantiated?

Comment: Just normally: `let mainController = MainTabBarController()`.

Comment: Did you try deleting the app and cleaning the build on Xcode and reinstall? Sometimes that fixes random things.

Comment: Yep, have tried that. I'm actually revisiting this issue because the infinite loop popped up in a different place, where there was also 2 levels of subclassing and calling `super.viewDidLoad()`

Comment: I tried reproducing this with a test app, but couldn't get it to crash! Here's the repo, though: https://github.com/ndbroadbent/SwiftSuperCrash

Will update if I can get it to crash on my phone.

Comment: If this is only happening in your TestFlight app, have you tried running in release mode in the simulator? Sounds like the compiler might be over-optimizing something incorrectly...

Comment: did you override `UITabBarController`'s initializer at all? also i'd log out `self.view` in each `viewDidLoad` call to see if it is `nil`

Comment: I'll try and debug it later tonight when I get some free time if you haven't found the problem by then.

Comment: @MikeWelsh - I've just tried setting my scheme's Build Configuration to Release, and turned off debugging, and ran it on my phone, but I still can't get it to crash.

Comment: @Nick - Nope, I haven't overridden anything in UITabBarController.

Comment: Have you tried removing optimizations and building? That's a long route to debugging, but it would eliminate that possibility...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/mobile-monitoring) in your app? (I'm guessing from all those `NRMA__voidParamHandler` references that you are.) I had this exact problem. I disabled the New Relic SDK and builds downloaded from Testflight stopped crashing. I haven't reported a bug yet, but you/I/we probably should.

Comment: That was it! I should have realized NRMA had something to do with New Relic. I've updated my POC repo, which now reproduces this crash: https://github.com/ndbroadbent/SwiftSuperCrash
Thanks very much!!

Comment: I've reported a bug on the New Relic forums: https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/reporting-an-ios-crash-caused-by-the-newrelicagent-cocoapod-with-swift/13539

Comment: To anyone reading this now, check Bryce Buchanan's answer, adding `dynamic` to the methods New Relic instruments solves this issue.

Answer (score 5):

with the addition of swift all the sweet dynamic function look-ups objective-c has is done away. To get that functionality back you'll need to add the "dynamic" declaration flag to all methods that New Relic instruments.

Like this:

```
class HWTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override dynamic func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
    }
}

class MainTabBarController: HWTabBarController {
    override dynamic func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
    }
}
```

More details, including which functions this includes, here: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-monitoring/new-relic-mobile/getting-started/enabling-swift-interaction-traces

Comment: Could this be connected to any Obj-C swizzles?

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded the repo, signed it on my own profile and everything seemed to work as you have it programmed. No infinite loop, no crashing. This is through Test Flight as well. This leads me to believe that you have some errors somewhere on your system. I suggest doing a few things...

1. Cleaning your build cmd+alt+shift+k && deleting the app on your phone.
2. Closing Xcode then deleting your derived data. (If you haven't done this before I can expand on how to do it.)
3. Registering it as a new app on test flight if practical.

My idea is that it will help when you delete your derived data but I would do it all just so you know everything is clean. Again, I did not encounter this problem at any stage: simulator, direct install from Xcode or download via Test Flight.

Also make sure the bundle ID is registered correctly and all is well server-side on Test Flight. I can't imagine why it would cause a loop but this is a strange situation so let's see what happens. :^)

Comment: Sorry, I tried to mention above that I also can't get the test app to crash, so it's only happening on our real app. I'll keep trying to add more of our code to the sample app to see if I can reproduce it. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: @nathan.f77 Can you post the code you have any `for` or `while` loops you have in the program if it init's anything? `viewDidLoad` should only be called once.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks again for your time! Another user helped me figure out that this was caused by the New Relic Agent trying to profile my code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27416135/304706

Comment: @nathan.f77 No worries, glad you got it figured out!