# NMRAThreadLocalStore currentThreadDictionary crash when using custom keyboard in iOS8

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, crash, exc-bad-access

There is seemingly NOTHING on the internet about this.

I am getting tons of crashes from NRMAThreadLocalStore/NRMAHarvester. I have been able to reproduce this by using a certain drawing keyboard (some custom keyboards crash while others work fine). I have no idea what this NRMA* stuff is, and it seems like there's no published information about this utility.

trace:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x000000016fc5bfd0 

libsystem_c.dylib   
localeconv_l
5
    CoreFoundation  
__CFStringAppendFormatCore + 11584
6
    CoreFoundation  
_CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 248
7
    Foundation  
-[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:] + 172
8
    Foundation  
+[NSString stringWithFormat:] + 76
9

NRMAThreadLocalStore.m line 239
+[NRMAThreadLocalStore currentThreadDictionary]
10

NRMAThreadLocalStore.m line 36
+[NRMAThreadLocalStore threadLocalTrace]
11

NRMAThreadLocalStore.m line 127
+[NRMAThreadLocalStore prepareSameThread:child:withParent:]
12

NRMAThreadLocalStore.m line 92
+[NRMAThreadLocalStore pushChild:forParent:]
13

NRMATraceMachine.m line 501
+[NRMATraceMachine newTraceSetup:parentTrace:]
14

NRMATraceMachine.m line 574
+[NRMATraceMachine enterMethod:fromObject:parentTrace:traceCategory:withTimer:]
15

NRMATraceMachine.m line 539
+[NRMATraceMachine enterMethod:fromObject:parentTrace:traceCategory:]
16

NRMAMethodProfiler.m line 883
NRMA__beginMethod
17

NRMAMethodProfiler.m line 594
NRMA__voidParamHandler
```

Answer (score 2):

I just learned that NRMA is the [New Relic Mobile Agent](http://newrelic.com/mobile-monitoring), since it was causing a crash for me: [I'm getting an infinite loop with Swift when calling super.viewDidLoad() in two nested subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26939195/im-getting-an-infinite-loop-with-swift-when-calling-super-viewdidload-in-two)

In your case, the NRMA lines in your stack trace might not be causing the issue, but you should try to turn off (or update) the New Relic Agent and see your app stops crashing.

Comment: Great insight. Curious why New Relic would be reacting to custom keyboards though. I'll disable and run some test.

Comment: Completely removed all NewRelic stuff and this is still happening. Wondering if the custom keyboard itself has NewRelic code in it that is going haywire. But that wouldn't explain why it works in other apps while failing in mine.

Comment: is there a way to capture and log all custom keyboards being used? would be helpful for tracing this down and really confirming it is a custom keyboard.